# Mate and Remote Java Services Integration

Tags: java, apache-flex, mate

I am new to Flex and need to integrate Java services with Flex UI built using Mate framework.

Can anyone point me to any website/links or show an simple example of integrating Flex UI on Mate framework with Java remote services?

A simple integration of a "LoginService" will be good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Christophe Coenraets has some examples on his blog. [Here](http://coenraets.org/blog/2009/10/max-frameworks-session-one-application-four-implementations-code-available/) is the link.